# Guardian DB Initial Setup (MyApp.Repo.insert/1 is undefined)

Tags: elixir, ecto, guardian, guardian-db

I am attempting to use guardian 0.14 and guardian_db 0.8 with elixir/phoenix. However, I keep running into the following error in the hooks:

```
    [error] #PID<0.983.0> running Api.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/login

    ** (exit) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyApp.Repo.insert/1 is undefined (module MyApp.Repo is not available)
            MyApp.Repo.insert(#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{claims: %{}}, errors: [jwt: {"is invalid", [type: :string, validation: :cast]}], data: #GuardianDb.Token<>, valid?: false>)
            lib/guardian_db.ex:87: GuardianDb.after_encode_and_sign/4
            (api) web/helpers/guardian_hooks.ex:12: Api.GuardianHooks.after_encode_and_sign/4
            (guardian) lib/guardian.ex:89: Guardian.encode_from_hooked/1
            (guardian) lib/guardian/plug.ex:183: Guardian.Plug.api_sign_in/4
            (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:81: Api.UserController.login_user/2
            (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Api.UserController.action/2
            (api) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Api.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
            (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.instrument/4
            (api) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Api.Router.dispatch/2
            (api) web/router.ex:1: Api.Router.do_call/2
            (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
            (api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Api.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
            (api) lib/api/endpoint.ex:1: Api.Endpoint.call/2
            (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
            (cowboy) /Users/me/source/proj/proj_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

My code is as follows:

Config

```
# Guardian config
config :guardian, Guardian,
  issuer: "APIAPP",
  ttl: { 30, :days },
  allowed_drift: 2000,
  verify_issuer: true, 
  secret_key: "SECRETSECRETSECRET",
  serializer: Api.GuardianSerializer,
  hooks: Api.GuardianHooks

config :guardian_db, GuardianDb,
  repo: Api.Repo,
  schema_name: "guardian_tokens"
```

Hooks

```
defmodule Api.GuardianHooks do
  @moduledoc """
  Used for hooks for guardian
  """

      use Guardian.Hooks

      def after_encode_and_sign(resource, claims, token, _options) do
        claims = if (claims == nil), do: %{}, else: claims
        with {:ok, _} <- GuardianDb.after_encode_and_sign(resource, token["typ"], claims, token) do
          {:ok, token}
        end
      end

      def on_verify(claims, token, _options) do
        with {:ok, _} <- GuardianDb.on_verify(claims, token) do
          {:ok, claims}
        end
      end

      def on_revoke(claims, token, _options) do
        with {:ok, _} <- GuardianDb.on_revoke(claims, token) do
          {:ok, claims}
        end
      end

    end
```

Why is it not using the repo I pass to it in the config?

In addition, I dropped a pry in there, and ran `GuardianDb.repo` and it returns `MyApp.Repo`. It's like it isn't taking my repo config.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message including the stacktrace?

Comment: @Dogbert posted. Also, some info on the repo I gathered from a pry. it's like that config just isn't taking with guardian_db

Comment: Is there any instance of the text `MyApp.Repo` in your codebase? Also, have you tried cleaning the deps and recompiling them once?

Comment: @Dogbert Nope. I checked for that and there was no instance of that text in my app. How do I clean the deps and recompile? Pretty new to the whole elixir train.

Comment: Try this: `mix do deps.clean --all, deps.get, compile`. It'll delete and refetch the dependencies and then compile the whole project.

Comment: @Dogbert Fixed it. If you will submit as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Posted an answer with the reason this (most likely) happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[guardian_db fetches the value of the `repo` key in the config at compile time](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian_db/blob/bcdfe62c61fcabf65240f28b20964b73eb57fbd0/lib/guardian_db.ex#L112-L113), which means you'll need to recompile that package whenever you change the value of `repo` in your config. This can be done by running the following command:

```
mix deps.clean --build guardian_db
```